# OnClickListener - Android Eclipse

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Simple question, but I am stuck :-(  I was able to make this work when following the tutorial exactly, but when I tried to recreate it, my button would not work.  There are no errors.  It is just that nothing happens when I click the button.  Any ideas?

```
public void listener() {

    Button btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bl);
    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            resetCounter(v);
            count = 0;
        }

    });

}
```

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Counter" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bl"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/btnReset"
        android:textSize="20sp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Thanks!

Comment: Did you call listener() in your OnCreate method?

Comment: Are you sure that the `resetCounter(v);` method is working properly? What is happening in that method?

Comment: foolish me. i never called listener().  thanks ahmad! please answer so i can give u the checkmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `listener()` in your `OnCreate()` method.